# How to convert a Map of one type to another, copy values from fields using lambda?

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a class

- first a type

```java
@Value
class BundleOne{

  private String first;

  private String second;
 
}
```

- second a type

```java
class BundleSecond{

  private String first;

  private String second;

// here is setters and getters
 
}
```

I need to transform

**Map<BundleOne, String> map1 = new HashMap();**

used lambda expression.

to

**Map<BundleSecond, String> map2 = new HashMap();**

Сan someone offer an example of such a conversion ?

**Update_1**

[image]

The picture above shows that I cannot get methods. Although I  tried to add the annotation @Lombok over bean (for our example - it is BundleOne.

**m** -  a is a local variable in a lambda expression that stores the current type processing object -  a BundleOne

Answer (score 2):

Classes with private fields and no getters are not of much use so I added them as well as a constructor.
This works as follows.

- create a stream of entrySets for the source map.
- Use the entries to get the b1 object and entry value
- Use the `getters` for that object to populate the new map.

```
Map<BundleOne, String> mapB1 =  ..<Source map with data>

Map<BundleSecond, String> mapB2 = mapB1.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e -> new BundleSecond(e.getKey().getFirst(),
                        e.getKey().getSecond()),
                Entry::getValue));

    
class BundleOne {
    private String first;
    private String second;
    
    public BundleOne(String first, String second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    
    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
    
    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}
    
class BundleSecond{
  private String first;
  private String second;
  public BundleSecond(String first, String second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
    public String getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}
```

Here is an example

```
Map<BundleOne, String> mapB1 = new HashMap<>();                       
                                                                      
mapB1.put(new BundleOne("A","B"),"Foo");                              
mapB1.put(new BundleOne("C","D"),"Fax");                              
mapB1.put(new BundleOne("E","F"),"Bar");                              
mapB1.put(new BundleOne("G","H"),"Bax");                              
                                                                      
Map<BundleSecond, String> mapB2 = mapB1.entrySet().stream()           
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(                                    
                e -> new BundleSecond(e.getKey().getFirst(),          
                        e.getKey().getSecond()), Entry::getValue));   
                                                                      
mapB1.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);                        
System.out.println("----------------------");                         
mapB2.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints (the output order may be different but the maps are the same).

```
[A, B]=Foo
[G, H]=Bax
[C, D]=Fax
[E, F]=Bar
----------------------
[A, B]=Foo
[C, D]=Fax
[G, H]=Bax
[E, F]=Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have getters, setters and a constructor with fields in both classes.

You can turn the entries of `map1` (`<BundleOne, String>`) to the entries of `map2` (`<BundleSecond, String>`) using `map()` function.

It should be something like this:

```
Map<BundleSecond, String> map2 = map1.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<BundleSecond, String>(
                new BundleSecond(e.getKey().getFirst(), e.getKey().getSecond()), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stream API. Use `Collectors.toMap` to collect as map where  newly created `BundleSecond` as key and map key's value as new map's value.

```
Map<BundleSecond, String> map2 = 
   map1.entrySet()               
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(
          m -> new BundleSecond(m.getKey().getFirst(),m.getKey().getSecond()),
          m -> m.getValue()));
```

**Note:** To access private field you need getter in `BundleOne` and all argument constructor of `BundleSecond` to create it.

Comment: new BundleSecond(m.getKey() - Here I cannot get getter....

Comment: BundleSecond - It is annotated  @Value from Lombok

Comment: For `BundleOne` getter is needed for private field and for `BundleSecond` a constructor is needed. You can use @Getter of lombok in `BundleOne`

Comment: I cannot. I don't have right to change Java beans . I only can use that  it is.

Comment: @Value
    class BundleSecond implements Serializable {
        private String field1;
        private String field2;
    }

Comment: BundleSecond is regular Java bean

Comment: `Here I cannot get getter.`  but I am seeing `bundleId.getField1()` in your solution. :( And don't understand why my solution won't work for you.

Comment: Sorry, I found an errror. Tomorrow I will try to write as I check.

Answer (score 0):

It is my solution.

```java
Map<BundleIdDto, String> map2 = map1.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        entry -> toBundleIdDto(entry.getKey()),
                        entry -> entry.getValue())
                );

private static BundleIdDto toBundleIdDto(BundleId bundleId){

    BundleIdDto bundleIdDto = new BundleIdDto();
    bundleIdDto.setField1(bundleId.getField1());
    bundleIdDto.setField2(bundleId.getField2());

    return bundleIdDto;
}
```